# React Native in HMS getting groovy.json.JsonException: Unable to determine the current character, it is not a string, number, array or object

Tags: huawei-mobile-services

When I am using React Native in HMS getting the following error
Error message: groovy.json.JsonException: Unable to determine the current character, it is not a string, number, array or object

Above error comes every time I try to run and build the React native HMS Location Kit.

Added all the dependencies and Location SDK in the folder and linked it.

How to solve the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uninstall npm by running
**npm uninstall -g**

and re-install in the project folder by running
**npm-install**

and link the project by running
**npm link**